# Build Definition cURL Protocol "D" not supported or disabled in libcurl

Tags: curl, continuous-integration, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Currently, I'm using cURL to FTP file from VS Team Services to Azure AppService.

But the log returned the following message: Protocol "D" not supported or disabled in libcurl

Am I missing any cURL parameter to FTP?

Note: I'm able to execute cURL from my local machine and file is able to upload.

Comment: Can you share your script? Of the task's configuration? And possibly the relevant lines from the log file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce this issue with hosted build agent if uploading multiple files through cURL, but it works fine to upload a single file. (Both cURL Upload file step/task and call cURL command via Command Line step/task have the same issue)

I submit a feedback here: [vsts cURL Protocol "D" not supported or disabled in libcurl](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/17635/vsts-curl-protocol-d-not-supported-or-disabled-in.html)

The workaround is that you can queue build with on premise build agent.

1. Add curl to environment variable of your build agent machine (path environment variable)
2. Restart build agent
3. Queue build with this build agent.

Comment: I'm quite new to this stuff. If that's the case, is it possible if I upload the zip file to Azure App Service and trigger unzip command?

Comment: @user970307 Yes, you can upload the zip file to Azure App Service via cURL. Regarding unzip command, you can try it with kudu api. Related articles: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API , https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/gabeshapiro/2017/01/01/samples-for-using-the-azure-app-service-kudu-rest-api-to-programmatically-manage-files-in-your-site/ , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26004816/unzip-file-uploaded-to-azure-websites

Comment: @user970307 If you just want to deploy app to Azure App Service, using Azure App Service Deploy step/task instead (In Deploy category).

Comment: currently, AppService is hosted in client subscription and the VSO in my subscription. Need to go through a lot of process just for the client to grant the access.

Comment: @user970307 Do you just want to deploy web app to azure? Azure App Service Deploy step/task is the easy way to do that. You can refer to this article to configure Azure endpoint: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/10/04/automating-azure-resource-group-deployment-using-a-service-principal-in-visual-studio-online-buildrelease-management/

Comment: Thx. This can be done only after client has granted access to their Azure subscription to my account.